# Is it safe to use a non volatile variable to stop the thead,which comes from logback source code?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, logback

I find that logback source code using a non volatile variable to stop the thread,is it safe?As we know,volatile can gurantee the visibility,but when using non volatile,it seems the worker thread may not see the new value of "started" variable.Although sometimes it works well.Can anyone can explain this?

```java
    class Worker extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            AsyncAppenderBase<E> parent = AsyncAppenderBase.this;
            AppenderAttachableImpl<E> aai = parent.aai;

            // loop while the parent is started
            while (parent.isStarted()) {
                try {
                    E e = parent.blockingQueue.take();
                    aai.appendLoopOnAppenders(e);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    break;
                }
            }
}
```

```java
protected boolean started = false;

public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }
```

The code origins from `ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase` and  `ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase`

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` keyword is also used to communicate the content of memory between threads. If a variable is not shared between multiple threads then there is no need to use the volatile keyword.

If you look at the declaration of the `worker` in `AsyncAppenderBase` class :

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
```

There is only one thread that would read the events from the BlockingQueue.

Comment: AsyncAppenderBase works in one thread,Worker runs in another thread, started is a variable of  AsyncAppenderBase,if  AsyncAppenderBase modifies the variable,then worker can not see it.